# vertical alignment at the start of each section

Tags: sectioning

I need to center vertically the start of the section.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\newpage\stdsection} %starts each section on a new page
\sectionfont{\raggedleft}                  %section title to the right


\begin{document}
   \section{Introduction} Some text here
   \section{Materials and Methods} More text here
   \section{Conclusion} Finish!!!
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the start of the section"? Do you want to have the titles centered? If this is so, simply change `\sectionfont{\raggedleft}` to `\sectionfont{\centering}`.

Comment: I want the page of the start of each section to start at about 1/4 from the top. Thanks,Natalia

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the mistake, but I actually want a vertical alignment...

Comment: No problem. Perhaps you could also edit the title of your question to reflect the fact that you want vertical alignment?

Comment: yep, i'm new to latex and to forums... thanks for the prompt reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package instead of `sectsty` (change the length `.35\textheight` according to your needs); notice that now the sections start in a new page using `\sectionbreak` and that this command also adds the vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\raggedleft\Large\bfseries}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage\vspace*{.35\textheight}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} Some text here
\section{Materials and Methods} More text here
\section{Conclusion} Finish!!!
\end{document}
```